# How to create solr password hash

Tags: solr

From solr [documentation](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/authentication-and-authorization-plugins.html#AuthenticationandAuthorizationPlugins-InStandaloneMode) to create a user I need to add following lines to `security.json` config file:

```
"authentication":{
  "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
  "credentials":{
    "solr":"IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0= Ndd7LKvVBAaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c="
  }
},
```

I know that under `authentication.credentials` the key `solr` is the username and value `IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0= Ndd7LKvVBAaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c=` is the hash of password `SolrRocks`.

But my question is, how can I generate that hash?
The documentation does not mention it anywhere,
It does not look like `md5`, `sha1`, `argon` nor any hash known to me.
After decoding the base64 it seems to be stored as some binary data.

What kind of hash is that, and how can I create it from bash?

Answer (score 0):

You'd usually [use `set-user` in the Authentication API to add the user](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/deployment-guide/basic-authentication-plugin.html#add-a-user-or-edit-a-password).

[rmalchow on GitHub has created a standalone version for bash](https://gist.github.com/rmalchow/51f5b23c2f59c687b001bfcdbf4bad5c):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
PW=$1
SALT=$(pwgen 48 -1)
echo "hash    : $(echo -n "$SALT$PW" | sha256sum -b | xxd -r -p | sha256sum -b | xxd -r -p | base64 -w 1024) $(echo -n "$SALT" | base64 -w1024)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this [online Solr password encryption tool](https://clemente-biondo.github.io/) that allows you to generate the required hash and salt.

[Github source repository](https://github.com/clemente-biondo/clemente-biondo.github.io)